# Could not determine java version

Tags: react-native

after upgrading to Java 9 , `react-native run-android` wont work

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'.
```

**react-native-cli**: 2.0.1

**react-native**: 0.48.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the Android tools don't support JDK 9. You need to revert to 8

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11755